# CSS Image Underwater effect

Tags: css, image, animation, transform, keyframe

So i'm currently trying to achive a underwater like effect on some images using Css Keyframes. I'm using "transform: skew" to do this but the result is not very good, and doesn't look organic at all. I would like the images to move and distort in a fluid way, as if they were underwater.

My Css:

```
 @keyframes imgevento{
        0%, 100% {
            transform: skew(0deg, 0deg);

        }
        50% { transform: skew(2deg, 2deg);

        }
    }

    .imgevento{
        transform-origin:50% 50%;
        animation:imgevento 6s linear alternate infinite;
}
```

Is there anyway i can achieve the result i want with css?

Comment: `underwater`--> so you mean distortion and waves, etc ?

Comment: I don't think CSS can do it... JS can though. https://ariya.io/2012/03/underwater-effect-with-html5-canvas

Comment: I'm on mobile/lunch so I can't really give you an extensive answer, but I would say you have way too few lines of code to make a fluid underwater effect. The first thing that comes to mind is that you're probably going to have to split images using ":after and :before" selectors. Like chop the image up in sections so you can animate each peace to give it an organic feel. It also feels like skew isn't the best option to achieve this. I will take a look after work, if no one have answered by then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think one key will be to put the distorted element into a container element and hide the overflow, to create a more realistic field of view.

In addition to `skew`, some additional filters, transforms and potentially CSS gradients could be applied to some pseudo-elements to create some 'light' effects.

It's also likely the effects will be dependent on the image used - to enhance or play off specific elements of the image, like light rays, etc.

This is just a start, using a container to crop the view, and some `saturate` and `invert` filters. Best viewed in Full Screen to get the *immersive* experience.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-width: 570px;
}

.imgevento-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.imgevento {
  transform-origin: center center;
  animation: imgevento 6s ease-in-out alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes imgevento {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: skew(0deg, 0deg) scale(1.35, 1.35);
    filter: saturate(100%) invert(0%);
  }
  
  25% {
    filter: saturate(180%) invert(10%);
  }
  
  50% {
    transform: skew(2deg, 2deg) scale(1.35, 1.35);
    filter: saturate(100%) invert(0%);
  }
  
  75% {
    filter: saturate(150%) invert(20%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="imgevento-container">
  <img class="imgevento" src="https://i.imgur.com/fypMB4q.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used this and it does look a lot better now.

I was thinking to implement a CSS gradient now to enhance the effect. Should i use this with pseudo-elements?

Comment: Would probably need to add a pseduo-element, with a sem-transparent gradient of some sort